# Слово "что" в предложении "Договор был расторгнут, ЧТО давало бизнесмену право на покупку автомобиля"

Tags: союзы, спп

Подскажите, пожалуйста, чем является слово "что" в данном предложении (союзом, союзным словом (местоимением)) и сложноподчиненное это предложение или нет (какой тип сложноподчиненного предложения)?

> Договор был расторгнут, ЧТО давало бизнесмену право на покупку автомобиля.

Answer (score 4):

Предложение сложноподчиненное с придаточным присоединительным. Союзное слово *что* (местоимение) является подлежащим.

Comment: "Придаточные предложения подчиняются главному и отвечают на вопросы членов предложения."(https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/735-21_obschaya_harakteristika_slozhnopodchinennyh_predlozhenii.html).  На какой вопрос отвечает второе предложение?

Comment: (https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/750-238_pridatochnye_sledstviya_plan_razbora_slozhnopodchinennogo_predlozheniya.html) "Примечание. В ряде пособий выделяются также придаточные присоединительные:
1) Вопросы: придаточные присоединительные отвечают на вопросы: **каков вывод из этого?** **какова оценка этого?** **что можно отметить по поводу этого?**"

Comment: "В целом сложноподчинённые предложения с придаточными присоединительными близки по значению к сложносочинённым и бессоюзным сложным предложениям. Не случайно союзные слова что, отчего, зачем могут быть заменены указательными местоимениями и местоимёнными наречиями: что → это; отчего → оттого; зачем → затем". _Договор был расторгнут, **это** давало бизнесмену право на покупку автомобиля._

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 2):

Параграф о сложноподчиненных с придаточным присоединительным нашел в учебнике Валгиной "Современный русский язык". Там и пример есть подходящий:

**Максим, покачивая головой, бормотал что-то и окружал себя особенно густыми клубами дыма, что было признаком усиленной работы мысли (Кор.);**

Я выделил жирным шрифтом наиболее интерсные места:

> [§ 118. СЛОЖНОПОДЧИНЕННЫЕ ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЯ С ПРИДАТОЧНОЙ ЧАСТЬЮ ПРИСОЕДИНИТЕЛЬНОЙ](http://yanko.lib.ru/books/language/ru/yanko.valgina_2003_416p_rasp_sl.htm#_Toc331394051)
>
> Присоединительные придаточные содержат дополнительное сообщение по поводу высказанного в главной части предложения.
>
> Дополнительное сообщение может заключать в себе пояснение, оценку данного в главной части сообщения, вывод из него или добавочные замечания, связанные с содержанием этого сообщения, причем в главной части предложения отсутствуют какие-либо формально-грамматические признаки, свидетельствующие о следовании за ней придаточной (за исключением интонационной незаконченности), т. е. она не нуждается в придаточной части, зато **придаточная имеет формальный показатель подчинения — союзное слово, причем значение его без главной части неопределенно.** Это союзное слово как бы вмещает в себя содержание предшествующей главной части (целиком или частично). В сложном предложении Одна из главных выгод охоты, любезные мои читатели, состоит в том, что она заставляет вас беспрестанно переезжать с места на место, что для человека незанятого весьма приятно (Т.) первая придаточная, присоединяемая союзом что, — изъяснительная, необходимость ее обусловлена семантической неполнотой сочетания состоит в том в главной части. Построение придаточной изъяснительной таково, что не вызывает необходимости в следовании за ней новой придаточной, и последняя имеет характер добавочного замечания по поводу основного высказывания (оценка его содержания). Это и есть присоединительная часть. Характер синтаксических отношений ее с предшествующей частью предложения напоминает отношения между частями сложносочиненного предложения, о чем свидетельствует **возможность замены союзного слова что сочетанием и это** (ср.: И это для человека незанятого весьма приятно), что недопустимо в придаточной изъяснительной. Собственно присоединительным союзом является слово причем: Портниха дело проиграла, причем ей не только пришлось вернуть деньги за костюмы, но еще отвалить истице тысячу франков за моральный ущерб (Наб.). В других случаях функцию присоединительных выполняют подчинительные союзы и сочетания.
>
> Подчинительно-присоединительные отношения выражаются при помощи союзных слов что (в разных формах), где, куда, откуда, когда, почему, отчего, зачем, как.
>
> **Наиболее часто употребляется в присоединительной функции союзное слово что (в разных формах): Максим, покачивая головой, бормотал что-то и окружал себя особенно густыми клубами дыма, что было признаком усиленной работы мысли (Кор.);** Он выстроил дом по собственному плану, завел у себя суконную фабрику, утроил доходы и стал почитать себя умнейшим человеком во всем околотке, в чем и не прекословили ему соседи... (П.); ...Лисий след она [волчиха] принимала за собачий и иногда даже сбивалась с дороги, чего с ней никогда не бывало в молодости (Ч.).
>
> Союзные слова почему, отчего, зачем обычно в сочетании с союзом и присоединяют придаточные с причинно-следственными и целевыми оттенками значений: Гусь взял в клюв другую веревочку и потянул ее, отчего тут же раздался оглушительный выстрел (Ч.); Брату нужно было сдавать вступительные экзамены в институт, зачем он и приехал в город; В лесу уже становилось темно, почему и пришлось возвратиться домой.
>
> Наименее употребительны в придаточных присоединительных союзные слова где, куда, откуда, когда и союз как, вносящие соответствующие их лексическому значению оттенки: пространственный, временной, сравнительный. Причем присоединительная функция их выявляется только в сочетании со следующим за ними и (где и, когда и, как и). Например: Он возвратился домой ровно в пять часов, когда и должен был прийти; ...Правда была в том, что он в самом деле лишился чувств, как и признался потом сам (Дост.); Ослабев от потери крови, Бенни пал на поле битвы, где и был отыскан в бесчувственном состоянии (Леск.).
>
> Присоединительные придаточные, в силу особого характера присоединительных отношений, располагаются после главной или — реже — в середине. Допустимое в отдельных случаях вынесение их в начало предложения создает характер инверсии: Что часто случается бабьим летом, с утра затянутое небо днем стало веселеть, и мягкое солнце без теней осветило землю (Фед.).
>
> Некоторые присоединительные придаточные в результате частого употребления превратились в устойчивые обороты: что и следовало ожидать; что и требовалось доказать; с чем вас и поздравляю.

Comment: Спасибо большое!